# using regexp_substr to separate format from other text in column

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table, that is some description of process.

I would like to use `regexp_substr`, but i don't know what im doing wrong.

i have an column that have some structure inside but everything what i have got there is a text like '`something is here THISIS.WHATIWANTTOGETINRESULT some other text is here`', i want to get string that is in format '`*.*`'

the pattern i want to use is just like this `[spacebar][allnumbers and characters][.][allnumbers and characters][spacebar]`

im using something like this right now

```
regexp_substr( s1.message, '[ ][[:alnum:]]+.+[[:alnum:]][ ]')
```

but it cut somehow string that i want but it leave one string in right side and one string in left side (example- string was 'asd asd asd asd.asd asd asd asd' and it cut 'asd asd.asd asd')

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong: (1) the obvious: after the dot, you have a plus sign; that should be AFTER `[[:alnum:]]`, not in front of it. (2) the less obvious: either before the needed substring or, more likely, after it, you may have things OTHER THAN spacebar: you may have comma, or period, or also the substring may be at the beginning or at the end of the entire string, so REQUIRING a space both before and after will miss the substring.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('something is here THISIS.WHATIWANTTOGETINRESULT something is here',
        'something is here ([^.]+\.[^.]+) something is here', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS output
FROM dual;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: hmmm in that case it works, but it was just example. Is it possble to use in pattern something that will define 'THISIS.WHATIWANTTOGETINRESULT'? And will cut only that string with that dot inside always? Because text 'something is here' in left side and in right is different in my table.

Comment: Edit your question and tell us the real problem.  Otherwise, I won't edit my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope this will meet your requirements.

Comment: i find the solution, sorry for making trouble. Anyway im thanful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i find solution

```
regexp_substr( s1.message,'\s\w+\.\w+' )
```

sorry for bothering

Comment: This might not work in every case, and it is not very specific.

Comment: hmm but i think it works in my case, every row that i have with message it cut everything that fits to '`*.*`'

Comment: That's great.  But what happens if the string has more than one dot surrounded by a word character on each side?

Comment: @Potato - it will not work, for example, if the desired substring is right at the beginning of the string (because in that case there is no room for the leading space).

Comment: hmm yee... I see now. Okey then, i haven't thought about that case. I will edit once again post. But that text of @TimBiegeleisen don't works in my database

Comment: Can you tell me how to put inside that what i made a must string 'DSS'? Because the string that is wanted to get in result is for example '`dss.sometext`' or '`fr.string`'?